# Routing Domain to Local DNS for Active Directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I've got an Active Directory using an external routable domain that is on premises.

The Domain is called "ad.company.com.au", i've setup my DNS in AWS so i have the following records:

```
ad.company.com.au NS ns01.company.com.au
ns01.company.com.au A {OfficeIP}
```

I've made sure i've allowed traffic through to the office.

But when i try from another server (in AWS) to Promote the server and use 'Add a domain controller to an existing domain' i get an error:

```
Encountered an error contacting domain ad.company.com.au The server is not operational.
```

I'm not sure what i've missed?

Also if i do a dig trace it says it can't get the IP for the NS:

```
ad.company.com.au.  300 IN  NS  ns01.company.com.au.
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns01.company.com.au': no more
```

but if i dig the a record it replies fine:

```
ns01.company.com.au.    300 IN  A   {OfficeIP}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what it is you're trying to do. Where is the Domain Controller? On premises or in AWS? Where are the clients that you want to join to the domain?

Comment: Sorry, the Active Directory (ad.company.com.au) is on premises, i'm trying to connect from AWS, to this Active Directory.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea, unless you connect your AWS instance to your on premises network via a VPN. Otherwise, you'll need to open up a bunch of ports inbound for AD communication. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd772723(v=ws.10)

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Yeah I've read this already and facing a tone of issue with the firewall (Cyberoam), i think the VPN option will probably be the best way to go.